# Change orientation pages only where a table is

Tags: vba, ms-word

My table goes beyond the borders of the page, I want to change the orientation of the pages where the table is located, but the orientation of all pages of the document is changing. The table is selected normally, but then the orientation of the entire document changes.

```
Sub slect1()
'
' slect1 Macro
'
'
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As when you use the Word interface, a page orientation change requires the addition of section breaks at the beginning and end of the rotated portion. Word's macro recorder can be informative. After deleting some less useful page setup properties:

```
ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Start, End:=Selection.Start).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
Selection.Start = Selection.Start + 1
ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.End, End:=Selection.End).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
With Selection.PageSetup
    .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .Gutter = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
    .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
    .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(27.94)
    .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(21.59)
    .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, the working solution is ```Sub select4()
'
' select4 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.End, End:=Selection.End).InsertBreak _
         Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
End Sub```

Comment: Yes, that's a condensation of my answer. If you found my input helpful, please upvote it, thanks.